# Customer Registration Error Magento 2.2

Tags: magento2.2, customer-account, 404-page

When I try to create a customer in frontend I get a error page (404 not found) and I´m being redirected to this link: customer/account/createpost/. 
I´d looked some similar posts problems and found a solution by adding

```
<?= $block->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
```

after my  tag. 
I´d done and it didn´t worked for me.

Any ideas ?

Comment: It seems that your Magento installation has some missing files. Please check whether the file **`[magento-root]/vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Account/CreatePost.php`** exists or not.

Comment: If you installed Magento using git checkout, then the file should be at **`app/code/Magento/Customer/Controller/Account/CreatePost.php`**

Comment: I don't think that the problem is due to formkey.

Comment: This is Not an issue of Formkey

Comment: Mohit, thanks for getting back. Yes, the file [magento-root]/vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Account/CreatePost.php] exists. And now?

Answer (score 0):

I also noticed that is not only a problem with the createpost page, but customers are not being created in my DB as well. 
Going ahead and answering a probable question, yes, I can create the customer just fine from my backend.